# jQuery Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to write a piece of jQuery code where, if all checkboxes are "unchecked", then all li tags have the class "disabled."

But, if one checkbox (any checkbox) is checked, then all [li] tags lose the class "disabled".

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want to remove 'disabled' class if at least one checkbox is checkd OR EXACTLY one checkbox is checked?

Comment: I want it if at least one checkbox is checked.

Comment: Thanks RaYell, your code helped tremendously!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$(':checkbox').click(function () {
    $('li').toggleClass('disabled', !$(':checkbox:checked').length);
});
```

Comment: You should use $('#myform input[type=checkbox]:checked') if you only want the checkboxes in a form with id myform.

Comment: I think you meant $("li") instead of $("*").

Comment: Yes, I notices that typo and fixed it.

Comment: You can just use `if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length)` rather than using the extra `count` variable.

Comment: I believe that you will also want to change your else if (count === 1) to else if (count >= 1).  Otherwise, if more than one box is checked this will fail.  Otherwise, very nice.

Comment: Read the problem description. It says if one checkbox is selected then it should remove the class not if at least one. Also I'm using the `count` variable to make the script faster.

Comment: Aberon, user hasn't clarified whether he wants to remove the class if at least one checkbox is checked or EXACTLY one checkbox is checked.

Comment: You should use the click event instead of the change event.

Comment: You can replace the branch with a call to toggleClass instead of two different calls (one to addClass and one to removeClass):  $('li').toggleClass('disabled', (count===0));

Comment: There is a shortcut for getting checkboxes instead of checking the type attribute:
$(':checkbox:checked')

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert> it doesn't really matter if I use change or click event in this case

Comment: Ken Browning>I could replace that if we would remove class if at least one is selected. If we have a case either exactly 1 or none is selected then I'm afraid it cannot be shorten.

Comment: Ken, thanks for pointing out the toggleClass method, very cool. :)

Comment: I've just updated the code. It now covers both cases (remove class if exactly one checkbox is checked and remove it if at least one is checked)

Comment: change or click does make a big difference. Have you tried it in IE and Firefox?

Comment: Yes, 'change' is broken in IE, 'click' would be preferable. Also, you should edit/remove the first code snipped as it removes the class only when exactly one checkbox is clicked and user clarified that he wants to remove the class if at least one checkbox is clicked.

Comment: The top answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event) is much cleaner and intuitive than all this `is(':checked')` business. :)

Comment: @Chiramisu: doesn't quite work, as the handler needs to examine ALL checkboxes, not just the one clicked.

Answer (score 8):

I came across this post by accident and I thought I would add my shilling worth:

```
jQuery(':checkbox').click(function()
{
    if (jQuery(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        alert("Checked");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Unchecked");
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't apply a class, or examine all other checkboxes, so doesn't really solve the OP's problem. Adding a click handler to checkboxes and then seeing if the clicked item is checked is kinda the easy part :(

Answer (score 5):

Slight modification of RaYell's, which will include any dynamically added checkboxes:

```
$(':checkbox').live('click', function () {
    $('li').toggleClass('disabled', !$(':checkbox:checked').length);
});
```

Comment: "change" is not a good event to capture for checkboxes. You should always use "click" (which is also fired when a checkbox is selected using the keyboard).

Comment: Excellent point, and one I should have remembered from previous code. IE doesn't handle "change" on checkboxes, for starters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':checkbox')
    .click(
        function() 
        { 
            $('li').toggleClass('disabled', $(':checkbox :checked').length <= 0));
        }
     );
```

**EDIT:** Thanks Ken for pointing out toggleClass method.