# Disable/enable element with checkbox and jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox and if I tick it I want a textfield to become enabled (disabled as default) and when I untick the the checkbox I want it to become disabled again.

I saw here [jQuery Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160238/jquery-checkboxes) how I caan toggle a CSS class and here http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F how I can switch between enabled and disabled with two buttons. But how do I toggle a textfields disabled/enabled status by tick/untick a checkbox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
   $('input:text').attr('disabled',!this.checked)
});
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FArMm/)

Comment: I think you want the change handler, which will fire even if the user clicks a label associated with the checkbox.

Comment: @Rao - if the it's label you're worrying, check [crazy demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/FArMm/2/)

Comment: Thank you for that, is there just an easy way to delete the text in the textboxes that becomes disabled and untick the checkboxes that becomes disabled?

Answer (score 5):

You can attach the change handler on the checkbox, and enable/disable the text field with its `checked` property.

```
$('#theCheckbox').change(function() {
    $('#theTextfield').attr('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/oludu3/2

Answer (score 1):

Here's a page that does what you're looking for - it's pretty minimal but shows what you need

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#testcheckbox").change(function () { 
                    $("#testtextfield").attr("disabled", $(this).attr("checked"));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" id="testcheckbox" />
        <input type="text" id="testtextfield" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Martin -to delete the text in the textboxes that becomes disabled and untick the checkboxes that becomes disabled - just add this line

```
 $("#TextField_ID_name").val("");
```

and to uncheck the checkbox, you need to assign ID name to the checkbox
and then add this line to the Jquery

```
$("#chekcbox_ID_name").attr('checked',false)
```

Hope this helps someone ... though I'm replying to Martins question after 2 years since his posting :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery 1.6, the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$('#theCheckbox').change(function() {
    $('#theTextfield').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

show and hide a textbox(#otherSection2) for entering other options when last checkbox in a rendered table(#CheckBoxListList) of asp:CheckBoxList control is selected

```
 $("#CheckBoxListList input[type='checkbox']:last").on("click", function () {

                if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#otherSection2").show();
                } else {
                    $("#otherSection2").hide().find("input").val(null);

                }
            });
```