# Enabling a Textbox using a checkbox in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, checkbox, textbox

We have tried to link the checkBox1 to txtCommentBox using C#. We are trying to make it so that the txtCommentBox stays disabled until the checkBox1 is checked.

We've done the below.

```
if (checkBox1.Enabled)
{
    txtCommentBox.Enabled = true;
}
```

After that failed, we then in the page_Load method, we've tried to do the below.

```
txtCommentBox.Enabled = checkBox1.Enabled;
```

That didn't work either. We've tried various properties with the controls with no luck.
The .aspx code is below, with the C# code further below.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Infomation.aspx.cs" Inherits="Infomation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Information</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 605px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <h4>
            If you would like to leave your Questions, Comments, E-mail, Name or Phone 
            Number check off the box you would like to enter into the form.
        </h4>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><span class="accesskey">C</span>omment:</asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox" runat="server" AccessKey="C" Width="334px" 
                        ontextchanged="txtCommentBox_TextChanged" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"
                        oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" Text="Enable/disable" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"><span class="accesskey">E</span>mail:</asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailBox" runat="server" AccessKey="E" Width="334px" 
                        ontextchanged="txtEmailBox_TextChanged" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"
                        oncheckedchanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged" Text="Enable/disable" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"><span class="accesskey">N</span>ame:</asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameBox" runat="server" AccessKey="N" Width="334px" 
                        ontextchanged="txtNameBox_TextChanged" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"
                        oncheckedchanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged" Text="Enable/disable" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"><span class="accesskey">P</span>hone Number:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhoneBox" runat="server" AccessKey="P" Width="334px" 
                        ontextchanged="txtPhoneBox_TextChanged" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true"
                        oncheckedchanged="CheckBox4_CheckedChanged" Text="Enable/disable" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="321px" Width="887px">
        </asp:ListBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
            Text="Back to the Main Page" />
        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've put our C# code for what where we're at, below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Infomation : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            txtCommentBox.Enabled = false;
            txtEmailBox.Enabled = false;
            txtNameBox.Enabled = false;
            txtPhoneBox.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("JoelsDefaultPage.aspx");
    }
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Enabled == true)
            txtCommentBox.Enabled = true;
        else
            txtCommentBox.Enabled = false;
    }
    protected void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox2.Enabled == true)
            txtEmailBox.Enabled = true;
        else
            txtEmailBox.Enabled = false;
    }
    protected void CheckBox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox3.Enabled == true)
            txtNameBox.Enabled = true;
        else
            txtNameBox.Enabled = false;
    }
    protected void CheckBox4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox4.Enabled == true)
            txtPhoneBox.Enabled = true;
        else
            txtPhoneBox.Enabled = false;
    }
    protected void txtCommentBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void txtEmailBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void txtNameBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void txtPhoneBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT #1**

Okay, so the AutoPostBack sort of worked. I can now enable the textbox from its disabled state, however I cannot disable it again.

**UPDATE #1**

I've updated the code to what we have now.

Comment: do u want it to be done on the client side or on postback?

Comment: We're thinking postback.

Comment: I think you should create a ViewState property and store the value of checkbox in it. On postback, you can set the value in ViewState to TextBox

Comment: So something like 
ViewState1 = checkBox1.Enabled (in the C# file)
txtCommentBox = ViewState1 (in the postback)?

Comment: how is the postback happening?

Comment: What do you mean by that, NoviceProgrammer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check the state of a checkbox, you want to be using

```
textbox.Enabled = checkBox.Checked;
```

Rather than the enabled state of the checkbox.

Comment: No problem, you should definitely look at doing this client side though as the other chap suggested, will improve the user experience.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is with this line

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  
     oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" Text="Enable/disable" />
```

It is missing autopostback="true"

 Combining it will be

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" 
     oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" Text="Enable/disable" />
```

### Edit-1

Here is a MSDN example for the same 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback.aspx

### Edit-2

But I will suggest you to use `java-script` or `jQuery` for the same.
Here is a good example

[Disable/enable element with checkbox and jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801970/disable-enable-element-with-checkbox-and-jquery)

Comment: It probably would be easier with javascript, I agree. However we're trying to do this in C# as that is the project requirements. I will give the autopostback a shot, and update you with the results.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.. Perhaps you are missing an else in all your events. As @MsB pointed out, you would also need to set AutoPostBack property of checkbox to true whenever you want to postback to the server... Check below sample **(Updated my answer to enable/disable via javascript as well)**

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2>Enable/Disable via checkbox server side</h2>
        <p>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbEnableName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                Text="Enable Name" oncheckedchanged="cbEnableName_CheckedChanged" />
        </p>

        <h2>Enable/Disable via checkbox client side</h2>
        <p>
        <label>Address:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbEnableAddress" runat="server" onclick="EnableDisableAddress()"
                Text="Enable Address" />
        </p>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function EnableDisableAddress() {
            var chkAddress = document.getElementById('<%=cbEnableAddress.ClientID %>');
            var txtAddress = document.getElementById('<%= txtAddress.ClientID %>');

            txtAddress.disabled = !chkAddress.checked;
        }
    </script>
</form>

protected void cbEnableName_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbEnableName.Checked)
            txtName.Enabled = true;
        else
            txtName.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll give that a shot also, and I'll update with the results.

Comment: It's worth high-lighting that the attribute for handling it on the server-side is `OnCheckedChanged` while for handling it on the client-side you use `OnClick`.  I didn't notice that difference when I was experimenting and wasted time trying to figure out why my client-side code wasn't working.  Anyway, good examples of how to do it on the server or the client.

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" 
                    oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" Text="Enable/disable" />
```

You must set "AutoPostBack" to true so that, when the checkbox is checked, it will reload the page and will run the your command in your if statement.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, I'll let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void EnableTextBox()
{
    int count = int.Parse(GridView1.Rows.Count.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");
        CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox2");
        CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox3");
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("txtration");
        TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("txtjob");
        TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("txtaadhar");

        if (cb.Checked == true)
        {
            tb.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            tb.Visible = false;
        }
        if (cb1.Checked == true)

        {
            tb1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            tb1.Visible = false;
        }
        if (cb2.Checked == true)

        {
            tb2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            tb2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EnableTextBox();
}
```