# jQuery checkbox checked state changed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I want an event to fire client side when a checkbox is checked / unchecked:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    // Do stuff
  }
});
```

Basically I want it to happen for every checkbox on the page. Is this method of firing on the click and checking the state ok?

I'm thinking there must be a cleaner jQuery way. Anyone know a solution?

Comment: @Arif I don't think they're duplicates because the linked question is about getting the state of a checkbox, while this one is about a checked event.

Comment: I always have to search for this checked property, there are many ways to achieve this [as written here](http://goo.gl/GQEf56)

Answer (score 1436, accepted):

Bind to the `change` event instead of `click`. However, you will probably still need to check whether or not the checkbox is checked:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

<strike>The main benefit of binding to the `change` event over the `click` event is that not all clicks on a checkbox will cause it to change state. If you only want to capture events that cause the checkbox to change state, you want the aptly-named `change` event.</strike> *Redacted in comments*

Also note that I've used `this.checked` instead of wrapping the element in a jQuery object and using jQuery methods, simply because it's shorter and faster to access the property of the DOM element directly.

**Edit** (see comments)

To get all checkboxes you have a couple of options. You can use the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
$(":checkbox")
```

Or you could use an [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']")
```

Comment: Actually I've got it looking for the checkbox by the class. Is there a better way to just get all checkboxes regardless of class?

Comment: You can do $('input[type='checkbox']').change() to get all checkboxes

Comment: @AnonyMouse - See my edit. There are a couple of ways to do it.

Comment: @Vigrond - Actually, clicking a label does trigger the click event on the associated control: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFG84/

Comment: This is much cleaner than `$(this).is(':checked')`. I thought you had to use the `change` event if you want to detect changes from the keyboard (tabbing, hitting space), but surprisingly, `click` also detects changes that aren't from a mouse click, not sure if it's a jQuery thing, http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/E39sz/

Comment: @JuanMendes - It's not a jQuery thing. It's an accessibility thing. If developers bind to the click event, what are users who are forced to use the keyboard or some other input method going to do?

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Very true, new fiddle that binds to the click event without jQuery, and still responds to changes with the keyboard: http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/E39sz/1/

Comment: _"not all clicks on a checkbox will cause it to change state"_ - Are you sure? What's an example of a way to click so it doesn't change state?

Comment: @nnnnnn - Hmmm. No, I'm not sure. Re-reading I belive I'm wrong on that.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Huh, not sure why I thought that!  Thanks for correcting me.  +1

Comment: **Please note:** Binding any event `click`, `change` or whatever to all checkboxes on the page can cause performance issues (depepending on the amount of checkboxes). Try binding to the parent element or the document and capturing the bubbled event i.e. `$('form').on('change', ':checkbox', function(){ //stuff });`

Comment: you can get the value of the checked box  use `this.value`

Comment: this doesn't worked for me. i changed the IF block to

`if($(this).is(':checked')){`
       ` //Do stuff`
    `}`

and it worked

Comment: It's better to use the `on` event because it retains the event when the css/prop changes (for dynamically created check boxes like the ones created within a template):
`$(document).on("change", "#check-select-all", function (e) {
if (this.checked) {
}
});`

Answer (score 151):

For future reference to anyone here having difficulty, if you are adding the checkboxes dynamically, the correct [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423235/247696) above will not work. You'll need to leverage [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) which allows a parent node to capture bubbled events from a specific descendant and issue a callback.

```
// $(<parent>).on('<event>', '<child>', callback);
$(document).on('change', '.checkbox', function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      // checkbox is checked
    }
});
```

Note that it's almost always unnecessary to use `document` for the parent selector. Instead choose a more specific parent node to prevent propagating the event up too many levels.

The example below displays how the events of dynamically added dom nodes do not trigger previously defined listeners.

```js
$postList = $('#post-list');

$postList.find('h1').on('click', onH1Clicked);

function onH1Clicked() {
  alert($(this).text());
}

// simulate added content
var title = 2;

function generateRandomArticle(title) {
  $postList.append('<article class="post"><h1>Title ' + title + '</h1></article>');
}

setTimeout(generateRandomArticle.bind(null, ++title), 1000);
setTimeout(generateRandomArticle.bind(null, ++title), 5000);
setTimeout(generateRandomArticle.bind(null, ++title), 10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="post-list" class="list post-list">
  <article class="post">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
  </article>
</section>
```

While this example displays the usage of event delegation to capture events for a specific node (`h1` in this case), and issue a callback for such events.

```js
$postList = $('#post-list');

$postList.on('click', 'h1', onH1Clicked);

function onH1Clicked() {
  alert($(this).text());
}

// simulate added content
var title = 2;

function generateRandomArticle(title) {
  $postList.append('<article class="post"><h1>Title ' + title + '</h1></article>');
}

setTimeout(generateRandomArticle.bind(null, ++title), 1000); setTimeout(generateRandomArticle.bind(null, ++title), 5000); setTimeout(generateRandomArticle.bind(null, ++title), 10000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="post-list" class="list post-list">
  <article class="post">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
  </article>
  <article class="post">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: NOTE: For parent (in above example: #post-list), you must use the element of document that is NOT being dynamically created. In my case, the div that holds the partial view.

Answer (score 28):

Just another solution

```
$('.checkbox_class').on('change', function(){ // on change of state
   if(this.checked) // if changed state is "CHECKED"
    {
        // do the magic here
    }
})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 16):

If your intention is to attach event only on checked checkboxes (so it would fire when they are unchecked and checked later again) then this is what you want.

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").change(function() {

    })
})
```

if your intention is to attach event to all checkboxes (checked and unchecked)

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {

    })
})
```

if you want it to fire only when they are being checked (from unchecked) then @James Allardice answer above.

BTW `input[type='checkbox']:checked` is CSS selector.

Comment: What if you want to find only not-checked checkboxes? I have this for all checked $("#tableUSNW tbody tr td[id=td1] :checkbox:checked"); but I don't know how to find all non-checked.

Comment: @FrenkyB try following: `$("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)")`

Answer (score 11):

Is very simple, this is the way I use:

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).on('change', '[name="nameOfCheckboxes[]"]', function() {
    var checkbox = $(this), // Selected or current checkbox
        value = checkbox.val(); // Value of checkbox

    if (checkbox.is(':checked'))
    {
        console.log('checked');
    }else
    {
        console.log('not checked');
    }
});
```

Regards!

Answer (score 6):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', 'input[Id="chkproperty"]', function (e) {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution to find is the checkbox is checked or not.
Use the #prop() function//

```
$("#c_checkbox").on('change', function () {
                    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                        // do stuff//
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 5):

It can also be accomplished as below. When the checkbox is fired, the div
or control with #checkbox id is hiddden or is shown otherwise.

```
 <script>
      $('#checkbox').on('click',function(){
          if(this.checked){
              $('#checkbox').hide();
           }else{
              $('#checkbox').show();
           }
      });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

> Action taking based on an event (on click event).

```
$('#my_checkbox').on('click',function(){
   $('#my_div').hide();
   if(this.checked){
     $('#my_div').show();
   }
});
```

> Without event taking action based on current state.

```
$('#my_div').hide();
if($('#my_checkbox').is(':checked')){
  $('#my_div').show();
}
```

Comment: on 'click' event doesn't work in this case. on 'change' works.

Answer (score 3):

Try this "html-approach" which is [acceptable for small JS projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769527/860099)

```js
function msg(animal,is) {
  console.log(animal, is.checked);   // Do stuff
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" oninput="msg('dog', this)" />Do you have a dog? <br>
<input type="checkbox" oninput="msg('frog',this)" />Do you have a frog?<br>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps this may be an alternative for you.

```
<input name="chkproperty" onchange="($(this).prop('checked') ? $(this).val(true) : $(this).val(false))" type="checkbox" value="true" />`
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this jQuery validation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
      agree: {
        required: true
      }

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('valid form submitted');
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="myform" action="" method="post">
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <input type="checkbox" name="agree" /><br/>
      <label>I have read and agree to the <a href="https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service">Terms of services</a> </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Agree</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

the key is:  use `prop` but not `attr` to query the `checked` status, e.g.

- correct:  `jQuery('#my_check_tag').prop('checked')   // return correct status`
- incorrect: `jQuery('#my_check_tag').attr('checked')  // always return undefined`