# Opening a Fancybox iFrame when checkbox is unticked

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to create a popup using the Fancybox plugin I'll explain the components:

- Delivery details form in a separate element with an id of #deliverydetails
- Checkbox with an id of sameAsCheckbox

Now I want the deliverydetails form to popup in a fancybox iFrame when the checkbox is unchecked. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$(function () {
    $("#sameAsCheckbox").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':unchecked')) $('#deliverydetails').fancybox('');
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#sameAsCheckbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('checked') != 'checked') $('#deliverydetails').fancybox('');
});
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. Do I need to declare any inline styles?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#sameAsCheckbox").click(function () {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  $('#deliverydetails').fancybox('');
 } 
})
```

[jFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DMM33/)

or you can also use this inside che click handler:

```
 if(this.checked) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423235/1479680)

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies which helped me get to the solution!

 $("#sameAsCheckbox").fancybox({
        'type': 'inline',
        'href': '#delivery_details',
        'titleShow': true,
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic'
    });