# Disable a textbox if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, textbox

I have an HTML table where there is a checbox and a textbox in everyrow. The idea here is every time a checkbox is checked, the textbox will be disabled. Here is the code:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Value1</td>
    <td>Value2</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="textbox" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="Blocked" onclick="myFunction(this)"/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>


<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(chk) {
             //disable the textbox here
        }
    </script>
```

Can you help me with this? Also, if I unchecked the checbox, I want my textbox to be enabled back. Thanks!!

Comment: So what's the problem? You didn't really try anything.

Comment: Hint: This tells how to detect a check or uncheck on the checkbox http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event. Or just read the "related" questions over on the right side of this page on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would something like below work for you?

```
$('.Blocked').change( function() {
    var isChecked = this.checked;

    if(isChecked) {
        $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find(".textbox").prop("disabled",true); 
    } else {
        $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find(".textbox").prop("disabled",false);
    }

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markwylde/LCWVS/6/

Compacted, it would look a little like:

```
$('.Blocked').change( function() {
    $(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find(".textbox").prop("disabled", this.checked); 
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markwylde/LCWVS/4/

Comment: Would using an ID be better then looking at the class?

Comment: Interesting. You set the attr true when 'isChecked' is true and false when 'isChecked' is false. The rest of those two lines is identical. (I do think your answer explains what is going on well.)

Comment: Also, you should use `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: nice.. in addition to disabling the textbox, would it be possible to set the text of the textbox to "0"? Thanks!

Comment: With `$(this).parents("tr:eq(0)").find(".textbox").val("0");` or using chaining for performance `.prop("disabled", isChecked).val("0"); `

Answer (score 2):

Sticking with the inline event handler:

```
function myFunction(chk) {
    $(chk).closest('tr').find('.textbox').prop('disabled', chk.checked);
}
```

The jQuery way:

```
$('.Blocked').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.textbox').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function myFunction(chk) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("textbox")[0].disabled = chk.checked;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="dateFrom" id="t2" style="width:100px"/>
<input type="text" name="dateTo" id="text" style="width:100px"/> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#check').change(function () {
$("#t2").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#text").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
$('#check').click(function () {
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
$("#t2").removeAttr("disabled");
$("#text").removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it allows you to disable and enable a textbox, if you want to disable multiple textboxes change it to getElementsByClassName("textboxes") then give all your textfields that class name.

```
function disableElement()
{
    textbox = document.getElementById("text");
    if(textbox.disabled)
    {    
        bunit.disabled=false;
    }
    else
    {
        bunit.disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Then have a checkbox and a textfield with the the textfield called text

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" onclick="disableElement();">
<input type="text" id="text">
```