# Why "event.currentTarget.checked" when clicking on checkbox is not correct?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, checkbox

We have a backbone program which will listen on a checkbox. When user clicks on the checkbox, it will trigger a function, but the problem is that the `event.currentTarget.checked` is not correct.

Say, there is a template contains a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show_user" />
```

It binds to a backbone view, and have such events:

```
events: {
  "click #show_user": "toggle"
},
toggle: function(event) {
   this.model.set("show_user", event.currentTarget.checked);
}
```

So if I clicked the checkbox to select it, I hope `event.currentTarget.checked` is `true`. But when we run karma test on Chrome(with debugger), we clearly see that it is `false`!

If we keep running the debugger line by line, it will be `true` after a while.

Why it has such behavior? Is there any other stable way to get the `checked` status of a checkbox?

---

Update:

I think I'm missing some important information. When I say `click` on the checkbox, I mean in the jasmine test, I write:

```
$("#show_user").click()
```

In this case, the `event` parameter in the method `toggle` is too early received that the state of the checkbox itself has not been changed yet. If I put it in a `setTimeout` with very short time, say:

```
toggle: function(event) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     this.model.set("show_user", event.currentTarget.checked);
   }, 1);
}
```

The `event.currentTarget.checked` will be correct.

Now I changed it to `change`:

```
events: {
  "change #show_user": "toggle"
}
```

And in my test, I won't use `.click()`, instead, I write:

```
var checkbox = $("#show_user");
checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
checkbox.change();
```

to change the state of the checkbox and trigger a `change` event. Now it's working well!

Comment: Is it any better if you change the event from `click` to `change`?

Comment: If changed to `change`, `toggle` is not triggered if I run `$("#show_user").click()`?

Comment: `.click` triggers `change` for me, check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bz0he3ep/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event

Comment: I tried this exact scenario locally, and when I do `event.currentTarget.checked` always matches the checked state of the checkbox.  In other words, the code you've presented here works, which suggests that there is some other code involved which you're not sharing that is causing the problem.  Is it possible you have another event handler bound to the same `#show_user` element, or to a parent of that element?

Comment: In a jasmine test, I need also to call `$("#show_user").change()` after `$("#show_user").prop("checked", true)` to trigger the `change` event. It's working now