# How to select the last element in div based on checked check box

Tags: jquery

```js
$(".a").on('click',function(){
   alert($(this).next('input[type="hidden"]').attr('value'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id">
    <div>
        <strong><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="a"> chbox1</strong>
         <input type="hidden" value="1">   
    </div>    
    <div>
        <strong><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="a"> chbox1</strong>
         <input type="hidden" value="2">   
    </div>    
</div>
```

How can i get the hidden element value when i change the check box status?
anyone knows let me know? 
Thank you

Comment: Curious, what's `<stong>`?

Comment: @j08691 its `strong` when the `r` key on your keyboard is stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hidden input in your code is not sibling of your checkboxes, your should at first select the parent element, using `$(this).parent()` or `$(this.parentNode)`.

```
$(this.parentNode).next('input[type="hidden"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input` is a sibling of your parent `strong` element, so first get the parent and then look for `.next('input[type="hidden"]')`.

Also, you could use `.val()` in place of `.attr('value')`.

```js
$(".a").on('click',function(){
   alert($(this).parent().next('input[type="hidden"]').val())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id">
    <div>
        <strong><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="a"> chbox1</strong>
         <input type="hidden" value="1">   
    </div>    
    <div>
        <strong><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="a"> chbox1</strong>
         <input type="hidden" value="2">   
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: $(this.parentNode).next('input[type="hidden"]').val();<br> thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the div element looked for with two `parent` method calls, and then `find` is used to search for the hidden element. I just discovered (in another [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8423235/2048391)) that also change can be used to detect checkbox select change.

```js
$(".a").on('click',function(){
   alert($(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="hidden"]').attr('value'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id">
    <div>
        <stong><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="a"> chbox1</stong>
         <input type="hidden" value="1">   
    </div>    
    <div>
        <stong><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="a"> chbox1</stong>
         <input type="hidden" value="2">   
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: $(this.parentNode).next('input[type="hidden"]').val();<br> thank you for your answer.

Comment: @prabhu My pleasure :-) I learned also something, the chosen answer used $(this.parentNode) which is probably the first time I've seen jQuery selector: $(..) applied in that way