# running an action behind a html checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I have some trouble with running an action when a checkbox is checked or unchecked. (i want to run the action as soon the checkbox is checked)

I tried with an action that makes an if statement run

```
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="check">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="">  Edited<br>

if (isset($_POST['Action']) && ($_POST['Action'] == 'check')) {
    var_dump('random check');
}
```

I also tried with a href that links it to another page which also didn't work.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="" href="ingevoerd.php"> Edited<br>
```

The goal is to run a prepared statement with an update Mysql query. Like this one

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE personen SET firstname=?, lastname=?, telefoonnummer=? where id = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($firstname,$lastname,$telephonenumber,$user['id']));
```

I prefer using php over javascript, but i am open for some sugestions

Comment: Do you want to run that as soon as the checkbox is checked or are you submitting a form? As in, should the page reload or redirect before the action is run?

Comment: i want to run the query as soon as the checkbox is checked

Comment: Then you're going to need yourself a dose of [AJAX.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) It allows you to send a request to your server and process the response without reloading the page.

Comment: any sugestions? haven't used ajax alot and kinda on a deadline, thank you

Comment: Sorry, you've just got to learn how to do it. Put your HTML in one file, your PHP in another. Perform an AJAX request to, for example, `updateperson.php` [when the checkbox state changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event).

Comment: yeah, i thought it would have to b something like that, thanks for the feedback, i really apreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax because javascript handles the browser side operations if you want to do on the server side you must need a submit button to post the data to the server.OR put this checkbox in FORM place an  event in jquery on click And submit form automatically on click event