# date_select: how to override value with a checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my form I have two date fields, `:start_date` and `:end_date`, related to a job. There is a month and a year.

Just like on LinkedIn, the end year might not be relevant, for your current job.

Therefore, I'm looking for the way to replace the `:end_date` with `"present"` when the User tick the box "current position".

What's the right way to do this?

**Update**

My code at the moment: 
`<%= f.date_select :end_date, { discard_day: true } %>`

Comment: @Udaykumardas Wouldn't that just set the present date for good? The thing is there is no end date in that case, since the job has not ended. I updated with my code, which is fairly basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't set a value that discard's end date, I'd set `present_job` to true from the checkbox (add this attribute to the `jobs` table).  This would ignore or clear the end date.

```
before_validation :clear_end_date, :if => :present_job

validate :end_date, :presence => true, :unless => present_job

def clear_end_date
  self.end_date = nil
end
```

Also, use this checkbox to visually disable and clear the end_date in the form.  You just need to add an event to see if the state changes and update the end date field.

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        // Disable end_date select box and make other visual changes
    }
});
```

[jQuery checkbox checked state changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event)

Comment: It works, thank you for helping me getting the logic of that.