# Set Values null in javascript for unselected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

> This is JavaScript Code :

```
var clinicalStat;
var id;
var val;
var clinicalVals;

$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  //alert(" you checked");
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   var checked1 = $(this).val(); //Inital value of checkbox is '0'
   alert("The inital value for selected checkbox = " + checked1);
   var checkedVal = $(this).val('1'); //value is change to '1'
   alert("The value after checked the checkbox is = " + $(this).val());
      }
    });

$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  clinicalStat = document.getElementById('clinicalStat').value;        //clinicalStat(type='textbox') inital value is '0'
  alert("The initial value of clinicalStat = " + clinicalStat);
 clinicalStat = document.getElementById('clinicalStat').value = "1"; //now clinicalStat value is '1'
 alert("Later the value is changed to = " + clinicalStat);
  id = (this.id);
alert("id = " + id);
 val = (this.value);
alert("val = " + val);
clinicalVals = clinicalStat + "^" + id + ":" + val;
alert("clinicalVals  = " + clinicalVals);

});
```

> This is my Checkbox code .

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="col-md-2   right2 fon">
    <h6>Clinical Practice/Procedure</h6>
      <hr>
         <p><input type="hidden" id="incidentClassifId" name="incidentClassifId" value="0"></p>
         <p><input type="hidden" id="incidentViewIndex" name="incidentViewIndex" value="0"></p>
         <p><input type="hidden" id="appendStockistStatus" value="0"></p>
         <p><input type="hidden" name="clinicalStat" id="clinicalStat" value="0"></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" value="0">Documentation</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalMiss" value="0">Missing Files</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalPol" value="0"> Policy not available</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalMed" value="0"> Medical records unavailable</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalCon" value="0"> Confidentiality</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalProc" value="0">Procedures not followed</p>
         <p><input type="hidden" name="clinicalVals" id="clinicalVals"></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox(this)"> Other (Specify)</p>
        <p><input type="text2" id="text" name="incidentClassClinicalVal" disabled="disabled" style="width: 92%"></p>
  </div>
```

> if i checked Documentation Checkbox iam getting ClinicalVal value like this clinicalVals=1^clinicalDoc:1
>   what my problem is how to get clinical values like this clinicalVals=1^clinicalDoc:1^1^0:0^1^0:0^1^0:0^1^0:0^1^0:0 i.e clinicalDoc checkbox is selected remaining are not selected.
>   if i select two checkboxes the clinicalVal has to show like this clinicalVals=1^clinicalDoc:1^1^clinicalMiss:1^1^0:0^1^0:0^1^0:0^1^0:0 i.e two checkboxes are selected remaining are not selected

Comment: i might be wrong about this but you can check this link ->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop your all the check box's and check for checkbox is checked or not

```js
var clinicalStat;
var id;
var val;
var clinicalVals ='';

$(":checkbox").click(function() {
  //alert(" you checked");
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   var checked1 = $(this).val(); //Inital value of checkbox is '0'
   
   var checkedVal = $(this).val('1'); //value is change to '1'
  
      }
    });

$(":checkbox").click(function() {
clinicalVals = '';
  clinicalStat = document.getElementById('clinicalStat').value;        //clinicalStat(type='textbox') inital value is '0'
  
 clinicalStat = document.getElementById('clinicalStat').value = "1"; //now clinicalStat value is '1'

var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('clinicalCheck');

for(var i =0; i< checkboxes.length; i++){
  
 id = checkboxes[i].id;
 val = checkboxes[i].value;
 if(checkboxes[i].checked){
  clinicalVals += clinicalStat + "^" + id + ":" + val+"^";
 }else{
  clinicalVals += 1 + "^0:" + val+"^";
 }
 
}
console.log(clinicalVals);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="col-md-2   right2 fon">
    <h6>Clinical Practice/Procedure</h6>
      <hr>
         <p><input type="hidden" id="incidentClassifId" name="incidentClassifId" value="0"></p>
         <p><input type="hidden" id="incidentViewIndex" name="incidentViewIndex" value="0"></p>
         <p><input type="hidden" id="appendStockistStatus" value="0"></p>
         <p><input type="hidden" name="clinicalStat" id="clinicalStat" value="0"></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalDoc" value="0">Documentation</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalMiss" value="0">Missing Files</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalPol" value="0"> Policy not available</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalMed" value="0"> Medical records unavailable</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalCon" value="0"> Confidentiality</p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" name="clinicalDoc" class="clinicalCheck" id="clinicalProc" value="0">Procedures not followed</p>
         <p><input type="hidden" name="clinicalVals" id="clinicalVals"></p>
         <p><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" onclick="EnableDisableTextBox(this)"> Other (Specify)</p>
        <p><input type="text2" id="text" name="incidentClassClinicalVal" disabled="disabled" style="width: 92%"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you for that man!! how to remove ^ in clinicalVal of last one checked clinicalVals = 1^clinicalDoc:1^1^clinicalMiss:1^1^clinicalPol:1^1^clinicalMed:1^1^clinicalCon:1^1^clinicalProc:1^ have to remove last ^