# C# ASP.NET How to retrieve the number or className of EditorFor via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css

so in my view I have this

```
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {  
                   @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].IsSingle)
                }
```

And depends on the number of Model.Count it will generate the Checkbox, sometimes it is more than 10 and sometimes it is 7 based on the List given from the Controller.

What I needed to do next is to check that if the user ticked one of the IsSingle, then another div will be displays.

```
            $(document).ready(function () {


                if (document.getElementById("Single").checked == true) {
                    $("#tdSingle").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#tdSingle").hide();

                }

                });
            });
```

I need to tweak the above code so that It will display the #tdSingle, if any of the checkbox is ticked.
Anyone know how to achieve that?

This is the sample of the EditorFor code being generated

```
<input class="check-box" id="z0__IsSingle" name="[0].IsSingle" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Sorry if I am being unclear.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can use $.change event handler (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event) with the selector provided by Ricardo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildcards in jQuery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `JQuery` selector to verify if any checkbox tht has "IsSingle" in name is checked:

```
var isSingleChecked = $("input[name*='IsSingle']:checked").length > 0;
```

`name*='IsSingle'` will find any input where its name contains "IsSingle", and `:checked` will guarantee that is checked.

Reference to JQuery documentation:
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/
https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/