# OnClick action is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my Laravel app when I click on checkbox it is not doing anything which is declared in my JQuery script.
Checkbox:

`<input type="checkbox" id="terms_info" name="terms_info"/>`

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    alert('home is ready');

    $("#terms_info").on("click",function() {
        alert('home is checked');
    });
});
```

Also, there are no errors in the console on Firefox dev tools.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: When you click the checkbox, can you run var x = $("#terms_info") in the console or step through and look at the everything and see if it shows you checked it?

Comment: its not replicable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery checkbox checked state changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event)

Comment: @Jamesking56 this topic didn't help

Comment: move it outside document ready. are you creating it dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `change` event with event delagation `on()` instead :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("change", "#terms_info", function() {
     if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        alert('home is checked');
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="terms_info" name="terms_info" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        alert('home is ready');

        $(document).on("click", "#terms_info",function() {
            alert('home is checked');
        });
    });

</script>
```

and you tell me if it works...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#terms_info").click(function() {
            alert('home is checked');
        });
    });
```