# Display and sum values from selected checkboxes different in divs at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm super new here, so this question might seem stupid to you.

I have a website in which I show some checkboxes. Those checkboxes have some values that need to be summed with a price, and they also have a text that need to be and displayed in a div.

[Here's the demo website](http://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/home-configurator/checkout.php?tipo=A.2&stile=contemporary&allestimento=silver), as you can see, the checkboxes need to sum their own price with the orange pices (they have two different `divs`), and then insert the value inside the `div` with `id=plus-display`.

For now I guessed this solutions but it's not working at all.

```js
var basicPrice = 784 ; // This is how we start
function getCheck() {
var currentPrice = basicPrice; // every time
 CurrentPrice = basicPrice,
   plus = [],
   total = 0;
   console.log(currentPrice)
  $("input[id^=plus]").each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      total += +this.value;
      plus.push($("[for=" +this.id + "]").html()); // get the label text
    }
  });

 $("#plus-display").html(plus.join(", "));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="rata-display-1" class="span text-sottotitolo_dimensione _2 rata checkout">784 €</span>

<br> <br><br>

<div id="plus-display" class="text_piccolo black checkout">PLUS:<strong>place in which display the name of the checkboxes</strong></div>

<br><br><br>

<span id="rata-display-2" class="prezzo-checkout">784 €</span>

<br><br><br>

<form id="plus" name="plus" data-name="plus" class="form-5">
          <div class="plus-wrapper interior-pack w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="interior-pack" name="interior-pack" data-name="interior-pack" value="25" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="interior-pack" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Interior Pack<br></strong>+25 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper domotica w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="domotica" name="domotica" data-name="domotica" value="7" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="domotica" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Sicurezza Domotica<br>‍</strong>+7 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper security w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="security-plus" name="security-plus" data-name="security-plus" value="9" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Security Plus<br>‍</strong>+9 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper emotion w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="emotion" name="emotion" data-name="emotion" value="15" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="emotion" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Emotion<br>‍‍</strong>+15 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper box-auto w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="box-auto" name="box-auto" data-name="box-auto" value="123" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Box Auto<br>‍‍</strong>+123 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper assicurazione w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="assicurazione" name="assicurazione" data-name="assicurazione" value="4" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="assicurazione" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Assicurazione<br>‍</strong>+4 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper wellness w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="wellness" name="wellness" data-name="wellness" value="45" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="wellness" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Wellness<br>‍‍</strong>+45 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper outdoor w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="outdoor" name="outdoor" data-name="outdoor" value="36" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="outdoor" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Outdoor Pack<br>‍</strong>+36 € al mese</label></div>
</form>
```

Comment: services is a array where names are stored?

Comment: Sorry, my error.. i've edited the question.. it's not service but plus.. i want to join the data from the `id=plus` in the div with `id=plus-display`

Comment: `.join` **will not sum** values in array, it will just join them with `,` as separator. Is this what you want?

Comment: if you want it summed, you can use `reduce` array method. https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/Reduce#Example:_Sum_up_all_values_within_an_array

Comment: yes, it's correct.. I want to join their name in the `div` with `id=plus-display` and then, at the same time, I want to sum the values of the checkboxes with the two divs with `id=rata-display-1` and `id=rata-display-1`.

Comment: @StefanoZanetti check my answer now. Logic is there, just adjust to your code :). Remember that when you *uncheck* checkbox you need to subtract from sum (I think currently no other answer than mine does that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add a event listener on checkbox. So each time it changes, you can recompute what you need. In addition I have changed the selector for the foreach because you don't have id starting by plus... Hope it helps.

```js
var basicPrice = 784 ; // This is how we start
$(document).on('change','input[type=checkbox]', getCheck);
function getCheck() {
var currentPrice = basicPrice; // every time
 CurrentPrice = basicPrice,
   plus = [],
   total = 0;
   console.log(currentPrice)
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, el) {
   
    if ($(el).is(":checked")) {
     
      total += parseInt($(el).val());
      console.log(total);
      // UPDATE:
      plus.push($(el).data('name')); // get the label text
    }
  });

 $("#plus-display").html(plus.join(", "));
 $('#rata-display-2').html(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="rata-display-1" class="span text-sottotitolo_dimensione _2 rata checkout">784 €</span>

<br> <br><br>

<div id="plus-display" class="text_piccolo black checkout">PLUS:<strong>place in which display the name of the checkboxes</strong></div>

<br><br><br>

<span id="rata-display-2" class="prezzo-checkout">784 €</span>

<br><br><br>

<form id="plus" name="plus" data-name="plus" class="form-5">
          <div class="plus-wrapper interior-pack w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="interior-pack" name="interior-pack" data-name="interior-pack" value="25" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="interior-pack" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Interior Pack<br></strong>+25 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper domotica w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="domotica" name="domotica" data-name="domotica" value="7" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="domotica" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Sicurezza Domotica<br>‍</strong>+7 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper security w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="security-plus" name="security-plus" data-name="security-plus" value="9" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Security Plus<br>‍</strong>+9 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper emotion w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="emotion" name="emotion" data-name="emotion" value="15" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="emotion" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Emotion<br>‍‍</strong>+15 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper box-auto w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="box-auto" name="box-auto" data-name="box-auto" value="123" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Box Auto<br>‍‍</strong>+123 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper assicurazione w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="assicurazione" name="assicurazione" data-name="assicurazione" value="4" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="assicurazione" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Assicurazione<br>‍</strong>+4 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper wellness w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="wellness" name="wellness" data-name="wellness" value="45" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="wellness" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Wellness<br>‍‍</strong>+45 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper outdoor w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="outdoor" name="outdoor" data-name="outdoor" value="36" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="outdoor" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Outdoor Pack<br>‍</strong>+36 € al mese</label></div>
</form>
```

Comment: It worked! i've a question.. instead to push the html from this line: `plus.push($("[for=" +this.id + "]").html());` is it possible to push the `name` or `data-name`?

Something like that--> `plus.push($("[for=" +this.id + "]").data(name));` ??

Comment: I have used the element to get the data-name. Check if it what you want. Regards

Answer (score 2):

Pure JS solution:

```
const form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]

form.addEventListener("click", (e) => { // taking advantage of eventBubbling here
  const target = e.target

  if(String(target).toLowerCase().includes("input")) { // naive check if clicked element is input - you should implement better check most probably
    const clickedCheckboxValue = parseFloat(target.value)
    const currentSumElement = document.querySelector("#sum") 
    const currentSum = parseFloat(currentSumElement.innerText)    

    currentSumElement.innerText = target.checked
      ? currentSum + clickedCheckboxValue 
      : currentSum - clickedCheckboxValue 
  }
})
```

When is this code getting fired? You don't have any kind of `eventListener` here, do you have it in your code somewhere?

Would be nice to know context of how this method is getting fired.

#### Generally I would advice different approach:

- add event listener to each checkbox (or to their common parent, so you can take advantage of eventBubbling - this is common scenario)
- on click, check if clicked checkbox is:

  - checked - you should add to your sum
  - unchecked - you should subtract from your sum
- get value that is next to checkbox
- add/subtract to sum

Also please describe what should happen in more details. 
ex. 
on `#someID` click get value that is in `.someClassName` and add/subtract it to value that is in `#someOtherID`

Rough sketch in codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGaVoe

Answer (score 2):

I just created one simple solution. May be it will be easier. 
The steps are as follows :

1. **Declare a Click event on the class that you added on all the
   checkbox** ("I am assuming check-plus is the class that available on
   the checkboxes only")
2. **On the click event just call the .each in
   JQuery and calculate the total sum and display that..**

Please take a look into the code sample to understand properly.

```js
$('.check-plus').click(function(e){
let sum = 784; // Base Price
 $(":checked").each(function(){
     //   console.log($(this).val());
        sum = sum + Number($(this).val());
     //   console.log("Total Amount :",sum);
    });
  $('#display').html("Total Amount is : "+sum+"€");  
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="plus" name="plus" data-name="plus" class="form-5">
          <div class="plus-wrapper interior-pack w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="interior-pack" name="interior-pack" data-name="interior-pack" value="25" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="interior-pack" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Interior Pack<br></strong>+25 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper domotica w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="domotica" name="domotica" data-name="domotica" value="7" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="domotica" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Sicurezza Domotica<br>‍</strong>+7 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper security w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="security-plus" name="security-plus" data-name="security-plus" value="9" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Security Plus<br>‍</strong>+9 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper emotion w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="emotion" name="emotion" data-name="emotion" value="15" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="emotion" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Emotion<br>‍‍</strong>+15 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper box-auto w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="box-auto" name="box-auto" data-name="box-auto" value="123" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Box Auto<br>‍‍</strong>+123 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper assicurazione w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="assicurazione" name="assicurazione" data-name="assicurazione" value="4" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="assicurazione" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Assicurazione<br>‍</strong>+4 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper wellness w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="wellness" name="wellness" data-name="wellness" value="45" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="wellness" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Wellness<br>‍‍</strong>+45 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper outdoor w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="outdoor" name="outdoor" data-name="outdoor" value="36" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="outdoor" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Outdoor Pack<br>‍</strong>+36 € al mese</label></div>
</form>

<h2 id="display">

</h2>
```

Comment: it wored! but i've another question.. it is possible to display the `name` of the checkboxes in a div with `id=plus-display` like that?  `$("#plus-display").html(plus.join(", "));`

Comment: Yes It is possible... https://jsfiddle.net/jub19tav/16/ Please look at this code..

Answer (score 1):

Your input does not have an ID that starts with `plus`, and so your selector is at fault here. 
You can use `form#plus div[class^=plus-] input` as your selector. This limits the scope of the selector as well as to avoid collision.

in the first lines of your javascript there also seems to be something going on:

```
var currentPrice = basicPrice; // every time
 CurrentPrice = basicPrice,
   plus = [],
   total = 0;
```

You probably didnt meen to setup `currentPrice` AND `CurrentPrice` (two different variables) - And your missing `var` keyword in front of the declaration.

Hope this helps, without taking the fun out of coding it for you! :)

Comment: Looking at it, you can also remove the `div[class^=plus-]` from the selector if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

This is achievable using JQuery, but I actually modified your `span` tag to separate with the currency so that the value is dynamic (*however I only tested it with one checkout value*)... 
Be sure to use `parseInt()` to retrieve the text in the `span` tag to make it into **number**.
 Suggest you to ref to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event) to have a better concept of this idea.

```js
$(".check-plus").on("change",function(){
var basic = 784;
$(".check-plus").each(function(){
   if(this.checked){
basic += parseInt(this.getAttribute("value"))
name += this.getAttribute("name")+"<br>"
}
})
$(".checkout.rata").text(basic);
$("#plus-display").html(name)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="rata-display-1" class="span text-sottotitolo_dimensione _2 rata checkout">784</span><span class='currency'> €</span>

<br> <br><br>

<div id="plus-display" class="text_piccolo black checkout">PLUS:<strong>place in which display the name of the checkboxes</strong></div>

<br><br><br>

<span id="rata-display-2" class="prezzo-checkout">784 €</span>

<br><br><br>

<form id="plus" name="plus" data-name="plus" class="form-5">
          <div class="plus-wrapper interior-pack w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="interior-pack" name="interior-pack" data-name="interior-pack" value="25" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="interior-pack" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Interior Pack<br></strong>+25 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper domotica w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="domotica" name="domotica" data-name="domotica" value="7" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="domotica" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Sicurezza Domotica<br>‍</strong>+7 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper security w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="security-plus" name="security-plus" data-name="security-plus" value="9" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Security Plus<br>‍</strong>+9 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper emotion w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="emotion" name="emotion" data-name="emotion" value="15" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="emotion" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Emotion<br>‍‍</strong>+15 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper box-auto w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="box-auto" name="box-auto" data-name="box-auto" value="123" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="checkbox-3" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Box Auto<br>‍‍</strong>+123 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper assicurazione w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="assicurazione" name="assicurazione" data-name="assicurazione" value="4" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="assicurazione" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Assicurazione<br>‍</strong>+4 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper wellness w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="wellness" name="wellness" data-name="wellness" value="45" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="wellness" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Wellness<br>‍‍</strong>+45 € al mese</label></div>
          <div class="plus-wrapper outdoor w-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="outdoor" name="outdoor" data-name="outdoor" value="36" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input"><label for="outdoor" class="checkout-text w-form-label"><strong>Outdoor Pack<br>‍</strong>+36 € al mese</label></div>
</form>
```