# How to check all checkboxes in a table and do a job for each checkbox with JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a table which is contains a td that have checkbox for each row when clicking on the checkbox all the td values converting into an inputs that contains values.
I want to do the job of each checkbox when check all the checkboxes in the same time.

This GIF will explain what I mean clearly:

[image]

And This is my html code:

```
    <form method="post" id="update_form">
        <table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped responsive-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkall" class="checkall"/></th>
                    <th>اسم الصنف</th>
                    <th>الكمية</th>
                    <th>السعر</th>
                    <th>القيمة</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="order_items"></tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="multiple_update" id="multiple_update" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="تعديل الطلب" disabled/>
    </form>
```

My JS code for checking all the checkboxes:

```
        $(document).on('click', '.checkall', function(){
            if (this.checked) {
                $(".check_box").prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(".check_box").prop("checked", false);
            }   
        });
```

And the JS code for fetching the data:

```
        // Fetching the order details
        function fetch_data(){
            var id = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
            $.ajax({
                url:"pages/Model/GetOrderDetails.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{id:id},
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    var html = '';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
                    {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+data[count].ID+'" data-name="'+data[count].item_name+'" data-quantity="'+data[count].quantity+'" data-price="'+data[count].price+'" data-total="'+data[count].total+'" class="check_box"/></td>';
                        html += '<td class="col-lg-4">'+data[count].item_name+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].quantity+'</td>';
                        html += '<td>'+data[count].price+'.00</td>';
                        html += '<td class="total">'+data[count].total+'.00</td>';
                        html += '</tr>';
                    }
                    html += '<td colspan="4" style="font-weight:600">الإجمالي</td>';
                    html += '<td id="gross_amount" style="font-weight:600">'+fetch_order_value();+'</td>';
                    $('#order_items').html(html);
                }
            });
        }
        fetch_data();
```

And JS for the job of each td checkbox in the table:

```
        // On check edit on order
        $(document).on('click', '.check_box', function(){
            var html = '';
            var id = $(this).attr('ID');
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'pages/Model/GetItemName.php',
                data:{name:name},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#name'+id).html(data);
                }
            });
            
            if(this.checked)
            {
                $('#multiple_update').removeAttr('disabled');
                html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('ID')+'" data-name="'+$(this).data('name')+'" data-quantity="'+$(this).data('quantity')+'" data-price="'+$(this).data('price')+'" data-total="'+$(this).data('total')+'" class="check_box" checked/></td>';
                html += '<td class="col-lg-4"><select id="name'+id+'" name="name[]" class="form-control name"></select></td>';
                html += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity" min="1" required value="'+$(this).data("quantity")+'"/></td>';
                html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="form-control price" value="'+$(this).data("price")+'.00"/ readonly></td></td>';
                html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" class="form-control total" value="'+$(this).data("total")+'.00" readonly/><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" /></td>';
            }
            else
            {
                html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('ID')+'" data-name="'+$(this).data('name')+'" data-quantity="'+$(this).data('quantity')+'" data-price="'+$(this).data('price')+'" data-total="'+$(this).data('total')+'" class="check_box" /></td>';
                html += '<td class="col-lg-4">'+$(this).data('name')+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+$(this).data('quantity')+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+$(this).data('price')+'.00</td>';
                html += '<td>'+$(this).data('total')+'.00</td>';        
            }
            $(this).closest('tr').html(html);
        });
```

I hope you guys getting my problem perfectly I did my best to explain what I exactly want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery checkbox checked state changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423217/jquery-checkbox-checked-state-changed-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's start with your 2nd code

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkall', function(){
   if (this.checked) {
        $(".check_box").prop("checked", true);
   } else {
        $(".check_box").prop("checked", false);
   }   
});
```

change to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkall', function(){
   $(".check_box").map((i, e) => e.click()); // <== here
});
```

**But please do you have any idea how to click on all checkboxes even if they are disabled?**
so i think you should move the code that handles the onclick event to a new function

```
   // OLD
   $(document.on('click', '.check_box', function(){
        var html = '';
       var id = $(this).attr('ID');
       ....
   }
   
   // NEW
   const onclickCB = function(){
       var html = '';
       var id = $(this).attr('ID'); 
       ....
   }

   $(document.on('click', '.check_box', onclickCB);
    
   
   $(document).on('click', '.checkall', function(){
        $(".check_box").map((i,e) => {
            e.checked =  !e.checked;
            (onclickCB.bind(e))()
        })
   });
```

Comment: The same solution before your answer but different syntax. It's work but when check nothing happen, when uncheck it's work right

Comment: So if we Just put it your edited code inside the if and else it will work perfectly. Thanks bro I'm really appreciate it.

Comment: If there is any solution for `.trigger('click')` when checkboxes are disabled?!

Comment: I made a small mistake and edited my answer, could you please review it?

Comment: Yesss this worked perfectly. Amazing. But please do you have any idea how to click on all checkboxes even if they are disabled?

Comment: What is the new function that I have to use?

Comment: I have edited the answer again, hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

After you check all/uncheck all checkboxes you can trigger a click event on the checkboxes, which will behave the same way as it the were all checked

```
    $(document).on('click', '.checkall', function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $(".check_box").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(".check_box").prop("checked", false);
        } 
        $(".check_box").click();  
    });
```

Comment: Yes it's work but when check nothing happen, when uncheck it's work right